# Proxy authentication with Twilio voice api in C#

Tags: c#, proxy, twilio

I want make outbound calls from my console application using C# With Twilio voice api. But most of the time i am getting the `connection error` message. My system is using the proxy server. So i want to add proxy authentication with the code. Please suggest.

My code is as below :

```
const string accountSid = "*****************";
const string authToken = "*****************"; 
var client = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken); TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken); 
var to = new PhoneNumber("*****************"); 
var from = new PhoneNumber("*****************"); `enter code here`
var call = CallResource.Create(to, from, url: new Uri(tempURL));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here.

If you're trying to use the proxy here, I think using our Rest API is going to be helpful. Try this code below to hook your proxy server up to the HttpClient object:

```
public static HttpClient GetProxy()
{
    // First create a proxy object
    var proxyUri = $"{proxyServerSettings.Address}:{proxyServerSettings.Port}";

    var proxyCreds = new NetworkCredential("proxyuser", "proxypassword");

    var proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUri, false)
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = proxyCreds,
    };

    // Now create a client handler which uses that proxy
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Proxy = proxy,
        PreAuthenticate = true,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    };

    return new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
}
```

To make the telephone call with the proxy, you can use the sample code here:

```
const string accountSid = "*****************";
const string authToken = "*****************";
string to = "+1xxxxxxxxxx";
string from = "+1xxxxxxxxxx";
string callUrl = $"https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls";
var httpClient = GetProxy();
var authorizationValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{accountSid}:{authToken}"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {authorizationValue}");
var result= httpClient.PostAsync(callUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string,string>
 {
     {"To", to},
     {"From", from},
     {"Url", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"}
 }));
```

Let me know if this helps or if you run into additional problems. Happy to help here

Comment: I want to pass a twiml also beacause we are using the text to speech feature of twilio.    var call = CallResource.Create(to, from, url: new Uri(tempURL));   here tempURL is twilio twil that we are passing. so how can include this in your code

Comment: UriTemp = String.Format("http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3CResponse%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CSay%20voice%3D%22woman%22%20language%3D%22en-gb%22%3EHi%20i%20am%20calling%20from%20Service%20Desk%20A%20M%20S%20Alerts.%20A%20High%20Priority%20incident%20P%20{1}%20has%20been%20raised%20in%20your%20service.%20Service%20name%20is%20{0}.%20%3C%2FSay%3E%0A%3C%2FResponse%3E&", servicename, Priority);

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Just catching up here. You can send the url by just adding a "Url" parameter and its value - like in this code sample: `var result= httpClient.PostAsync(callUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string,string>
    {
        {"To", to},
        {"From", from},
        {"Url", "LINK_TO_TWIML_URL"}));`

Here is the [link to the docs]( https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls#post-parameters)that list out the other parameters you can post.

Comment: Thanks....But this code doesn't trigger a call....Just created object with supplied values....How to trigger a call with this object....

Comment: Hey @Ajith I totally spaced on replying here. 

The reason the call didn't trigger was because i left the URL parameter off. Remember - that URL parameter is required for Twilio to know what to do when the call connects. I just verified the code again on my side. It definitely works. 

Let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: Does the SDK support proxy config? Ultimately that would be most desirable instead of reimplementing all the HTTP specific logic

Comment: Yup. I just posted a blog on this. The blog is [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/01/protect-your-identity-with-proxy-servers-twilio-and-c.html) and the source code is [here](https://github.com/clw895/twiliothruproxy/tree/completed). 

Because of how .NET support's proxy, you do unfortunately have to build the proxy object. But connecting it to the Twilio connection is really simple. Check out the [code sample](https://github.com/clw895/twiliothruproxy/blob/completed/Program.cs).